# XPath get all attributes filter returning value of a single instance only

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

Suppose I have the following xml structure,

```
<foos>
    <bar id="0001"></bar>
    <bar id="0002"></bar>
    <bar id="0003"></bar>
    <bar id="0004"></bar>
</foos>
```

How come the following xpath returns only the last id? Why not all id attributes? Is XPath doing a distinct by default?

And then if I change copy-of with value-of, it returns the value of the first instance of id? Hows this ordering re LIFO for copy of and FIFO for value-of happening?

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <info>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//bar/@*"/>
    </info>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: **Hint 1**: what do you get as a result of `count(//bar/@*)`? **Hint 2**: an element cannot have more than one attribute with the same name.

Comment: "*if I change copy-of with value-of, it returns the value of the first instance of id?*" Not in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: count returns 4. but copy of returns <info id="0004" /> and yes we are using XSLT 1.0 and need to find the answer with respect to that unfortunately

Comment: "*yes we are using XSLT 1.0*" Then you shouldn't tag your question as XPath 2.0.

Comment: Sincere apologies, that's a bad mistake on my part. Lemme fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer with regard to **copy-of** is roughly this: the first instance of @id creates an attribute named `id` with a value of `0001`. The second instance overwrites this attribute with a value of `0002`, and so on.

If, OTOH, you would have this XML as the input:

```
<foos>
    <bar id="0001"></bar>
    <bar ie="0002"></bar>
    <bar if="0003"></bar>
    <bar ig="0004"></bar>
</foos>
```

then:

```
<info>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//bar/@*"/>
</info>
```

would have returned:

```
<info id="0001" ie="0002" if="0003" ig="0004"/>
```

because now there's no conflict between successive instances of `@*`.

---

The answer with regard to **value-of** is that in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$node-set"/>
```

will return the value of the first node in $node-set.

Comment: Thanks heaps, that answers my question. So the distinct is by construct. Cause for elements it returns multiple elements if that exists but of course you cant have multiple instances of the same attribute on an element.